# Using grpc as client in webflux

Tags: spring-webflux, grpc-java

Our team's project is a product that accepts requests and then forwards them to processing business machines. We use Springboot's webflux as a framework and use gRPC in it as a client to send requests to business machines.

Its process is as follows:
User <-> Webflux <-> gRPC <-> The machine that actually handle the business

We were drawn to the asynchronous non-blocking nature of webflux and gRPC. gRPC uses streaming.

The controller and service we wrote are roughly as follows:

```java
@PostMapping(”xxxx“)
pulbic Mono<String> mac() {
    final COmpletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    final StreamObserver<MacMessage> request = gRPCService.getStub.mac(new StreamObserver<>() {
        String mac;

        @Override
        public void onNext(MacMessage value) {
            mac = Base64.encode(value.getMac.toByteArray());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            future.completeExceptionally(t);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            future.complete(mac);
        }
    });

    request.onNext(MacMessage.newBuilder().setxxxx....build());
    request.onCompleted();
    return Mono.fromFuture(future);
}
```

In addition, when I tried the Mono API recently, I found another way of writing, which does not require the use of CompletableFuture, and the effect is similar:

```java
@PostMapping(”xxxx“)
pulbic Mono<String> mac() {
    return Mono.create(monoSink -> {
        final StreamObserver<MacMessage> request = gRPCService.getStub.mac(new StreamObserver<>() {
            String mac;

            @Override
            public void onNext(MacMessage value) {
                mac = Base64.encode(value.getMac.toByteArray());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                monoSink.error(t);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                monoSink.success(mac);
            }
        });

        request.onNext(MacMessage.newBuilder().setxxxx....build());
        request.onCompleted();
    });
}
```

I would like to know whether the above writing methods have met the requirements of asynchronous non-blocking, and if not, how should they be used?

The reason for this doubt is that (taking the above code as an example) we found that if we only use printing to consume the response value in gRPC StreamObserver#onNext, the performance is much higher than the above two writing methods, and the performance of the above two writing methods is similar . This makes me wonder, is there such a big difference in the performance of printing the consumption response value and returning the response value?

Comment: The performance issue then seems caused by returning the response value - either the future or the sink being used

Comment: The response is only 32 bytes. Or do you mean what else does the framework do with the return value?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few ways you can create a `Mono<GrpcResponse>` ranging from simplest to most complicated.

First off you need a GRPC stub supplier.  Here's a simplistic one which provides all 3 stub types.

```java
@Component
public class GrpcStubProvider implements DisposableBean {

  private ConcurrentMap<String, ManagedChannel> channels = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  public ProfileStub forProfile(String serverId, int port) {
    return ProfileGrpc.newStub(obtainChannelFor(serverId, port));
  }
  public ProfileBlockingStub forProfileBlocking(String serverId, int port) {
    return ProfileGrpc.newBlockingStub(obtainChannelFor(serverId, port));
  }
  public ProfileFutureStub forProfileFutureStub(String serverId, int port) {
    return ProfileGrpc.newFutureStub(obtainChannelFor(serverId, port));
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {
    channels.values().forEach( channel -> channel.shutdown() }
  }

  private ManagedChannel obtainChannelFor(String serverId, int port) {

    return channels.computeIfAbsent(serverId, keyServerId ->
      ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(keyServerId, port).build()
    );
  }
}
```

## Blocking stub

Once you have the provider the first implementation may not be the most elegant nor efficient but it's easy enough to understand.

```java
Mono.fromSupplier(() -> grpcStubProvider
  .forProfileBlocking("myserver", 1234)
  .authenticate(req));
```

This simply calls the stub with a request to get the result.  This won't handle streams but simple unary calls would work.

## Normal stub (Mono)

This utilizes the Mono.create with stream handler.  In which case `onCompleted` is a no-op because Mono only requires one value.

```java
Mono.create(sink -> {
  final var stub = grpcStubProvider.forProfile("nyserver", 1234); 
  stub.authenticate(request, new StreamObserver<ProfileOuterClass.ProfileResponse>() {
           @Override
           public void onNext(ProfileOuterClass.ProfileResponse value) {
               sink.success(value);
           }

           @Override
           public void onError(Throwable t) {
                sink.error(t);
           }

           @Override
           public void onCompleted() {
               // no-op
           }
       });
});
```

## Normal stub (Flux)

The advantage of the last approach is you can convert that to a Flux which is more efficient for lists when you get streaming data.

```java
Flux.create(sink -> {
  var stub = grpcStubProvider.forProfile("nyserver", 1234);
  stub.authenticate(request, new StreamObserver<ProfileOuterClass.ProfileResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onNext(ProfileOuterClass.ProfileResponse value) {
      sink.next(value);
    }

    Override
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
      sink.error(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
      sink.complete();
    }
  });
});
```

My recommendation is not to use the Normal Stub unless you're doing streams.  The complexity doesn't really add much.